# sed: remove hex-character(s) within the first n characters of a file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a pattern like:

```
201404018^@133^@^@1^@^2^@31@1^@^32
20140401^@8133^@3^@0^@^22@1^@^3
201404^@018133^@10^@3^@^4@12^@^321
20140401813322^@97^@^@5^@^23
```

`^@` in the above represents NUL characters (0x00), and I would like to remove these within the first 14 characters (datetime), but keep the rest. Just like:

```
20140401813312^@31@1^@^32
20140401813330^@^22@1^@^3
20140401813310^@3^@^4@12^@^321
20140401813322^@97^@^@5^@^23
```

I have tried `sed 's/^[0-9]{0,13}\x00//g'` - but that won't really do anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying you have `'\0'` (`0x00`) in a string but consider it part of the string? How then do you know how long the string is?

Comment: @Floris: Binary data.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce your strings, so I can't easily verify a solution - but have you tried using `tr` for this?

Comment: Does "14 characters" include the zero bytes or not?

Comment: If this is binary data, then a string editor is almost certainly the wrong tool to use...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 's/\x0// while ($i = index $_, "\x0") >= 0 and $i < 14' input-file
```

For each line, it removes zero bytes while their position is below 14.

Comment: Works like a charm... I'll use perl for the rest, too ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Gotta respect the perl, answering only because you did ask about sed:

On GNU/anything,

```
sed -E ':a; s/^(.{,13})\x0/\1/; ta'
```

but handling nulls is a GNU extension.

Comment: Try `[^^A-^?]` since we're on it?  -- edit: nahh, that will miss the 8bit codes.  Too bad.

Comment: `^A` and `^?` are control characters for characters 1 and 127, ctrl-A = SOH and ctrl-shift-backspace = DEL just about everywhere, quote them on bash entry with `^V`

Comment: +1; nicely done - even shorter than the Perl solution (though probably not as easy to understand). Unfortunately, at least with BSD (OSX) sed replacing `;` with newlines - while necessary - is NOT enough: the regex doesn't support `\xnn` escapes there, and trying to splice in an ANSI C-quoted `$'\x0'`instead actually breaks the whole command (the shell's parsing interprets  `$'\x0'` as an _empty string_ and thus effectively _discards_ it. The resulting `sed` script - with the NUL missing - then goes into an infinite replacement loop.).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; actually, your workaround _does_ work with non-ASCII chars, at least in a UTF8-based locale - not exactly sure why, though. That said, to be safe we can tweak your workaround with the help of ANSI C-quoted strings again, and use `LC_CTYPE=C` to work around encoding issues; here's the complete command that works with BSD sed (at least on OS X 10.9.3): `LC_CTYPE=C sed -E ':a'$'\n''s/^(.{0,13})[^'$'\x01''-'$'\xff'']/\1/; ta'`; I will consolidate my other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Choroba's Perl solution is better, but it could also be done in Bash like this:

```
while read -r line; do
    count=0
    for i in $(seq 0 ${#line}); do
        case ${line:$i:1} in
            [\x00-\x7F])
                count=$((count+1))
                if [ $count -eq 14 ]; then
                    len=$i
                    break
                fi
                ;;
        esac
    done
    c1=${line:0:$len}
    c1=${c1//[^\x00-\x7F]/}
    c2=${line:$((len+1))}
    echo "$c1$c2"
done < file
```

Output:

```
2014040181331^@31@1^@^32
2014040181333^@^22@1^@^3
2014040181331^@3^@^4@12^@^321
2014040181332^@97^@^@5^@^23
```

Comment: The trick is they need not to count the removed characters in those 14.

Comment: You need to figure out how many characters were deleted before you can figure out where $c2 starts, no? Otherwise you end up with duplicate characters.